# Getting value from page with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following page structure:

```py
       <tr class="small data-row" bgcolor="#f9f9f9">.</tr> 
           <td class="stats1" align="right">0</td>
           <td class="stats1" align="right">0</td>
           <td class="stats1" align="right">0</td>
           <td class="stats1 stats-dash" align="right">-</td>
        .
        .
        .
       <tr class="small data-row" bgcolor="#ffffff">.</tr> 
       <tr class="small data-row" bgcolor="#f9f9f9">.</tr>    
       <tr class="small" bgcolor="#eff6ef">.</tr>
            <td class="stats1" align="right">215</td>
            <td class="stats1" align="right">183</td>
            <td class="stats1" align="right">0</td>
            <td class="stats1 stats-dash" align="right">-</td>
       </tr>
```

I would like to get this second value == **183**, but I am not sure how to do it. I tried in that way:

```py
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

for elm in soup.select(".stats1"):
    val=elm.get("align")
```

and the output is:

```
right
<td align="right" class="stats1">215</td>
```

if I got 183 instead of 215 I could use .split, but in this case I get only this first value.

Comment: "*and the output is:*" The code you've provided shouldn't be capable of printing `<td align="right" class="stats1">215</td>`; can you ensure your code is representative of what you're *actually* working with? [ask]

Answer (score 1):

`.select()` will return a list of elements. Just call that element by index:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
html = '''<tr class="small data-row" bgcolor="#f9f9f9">.</tr>    
       <tr class="small" bgcolor="#ffffff">.</tr>
            <td class="stats1" align="right">215</td>
            <td class="stats1" align="right">183</td>
            <td class="stats1" align="right">0</td>
            <td class="stats1 stats-dash" align="right">-</td>
       </tr>'''
       
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
elm = soup.select(".stats1")[1]
```

**Output:**

```
print(elm.text)
183
```